# Difference between tcsh and bsd-csh in terms of use of square brackets in echo

Tags: shell, ubuntu, echo, csh, tcsh

I have two simple Shell scripts that essentially do the same thing (i.e., printing all arguments), as are shown below.

S1:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh
echo [$argv[*]]
```

S2:

```
#!/usr/bin/bsd-csh
echo [$argv[*]]
```

S1 runs OK on Ubuntu as a tcsh script:

```
% ./S1 a b
[a b]
```

But S2 fails on Ubuntu as a bsd-csh script:

```
% ./S2 a b
echo: No match.
```

I know S2 can be fixed by a pair of double quotes around `[$argv[*]]`, yet I'd like to know what leads to the different results in tcsh and bsd-csh. If possible, please provide links to documentation that help explain cause of the different results. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you execute both in the same directory? Perhaps when running the csh script, there are no entries named `a` or `b` in the working directory.

Comment: `[blah]` is a filename expansion pattern that matches a file named one of the letters b, l, a, or h. If there are no matches, it raises an error by default.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes. I executed them in the same directory, which contains neither `a` nor `b`.

Comment: The tcsh option that controls errors on no match is `nonomatch`; dunno about csh.

Comment: @Shawn: csh also seems to have _nonomatch_, so I guess that this option is set differently in the two shells used by the OP. This would then explain the behaviour.

Comment: @zanetu : Edit your question to the setting of this option in your shells.

Comment: @user1934428 I added `echo $nonomatch` to both scripts before `echo [$argv[*]]` and got `nonomatch: Undefined variable.` as output for both scripts. I'd like to emphasize that my objective is to find out why S1 succeeds while S2 fails. I am not looking for ways to fix S2.

Comment: `bsd-csh` is of the original C Shell lineage, from Bill Joy's source code. `tcsh` started many decades ago (1983) as a fork of that code. It adds many features. It's not surprising that syntax which works in tcsh is not csh compatible.

Comment: What will you do when you know *"why S1 succeeds while S2 fails"*? In my experience, I would try to find a common set of code that will work in both. We appreciate that you have given an [mcve], but it is feeling like a `x/y` problem (sorry don't have a link). I think you'll have to look at the source code for both to understand why one works and the other doesn't. Documentation at the level you're hoping for doesn't exist (and would likely be wrong, as unmaintained while the code base changed). ...

Comment: If you must, get the Anderson's "The Unix C Shell Field Guide", Excellent tech writing at an end-user level. You may find a hint there. I would remove the `[`,`]`s per Shawn's comment to be sure they are not affecting your test. Edit : I've confirmed this Replace with `X`s and you will get non-error output. Good luck.

Comment: `nonomatch` is a zsh and tcsh option. I don't know whether it exists in csh as well. I'm not sure though: I haven't used cah for more than 30 years now and am surprised that it is still in use. In any case, _nonomatch_ would be an option, not a variable, so your `echo` does not make sense anyway.

Comment: @shellter I'm looking for documentation specifying default behaviors of csh/tcsh because one of my students asked for that. I searched online and found nothing. As a result, I turned to SO for help. Anyway, thanks for your info.